# Remove One Space Character with a Regular Expression (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, foreach

I need to remove one character / space in some dynamically generated content.  It's generated via a plugin that I can't change the code of.

The problem is I need to remove the space between the time and the 'am', so in the code below it's the space between the '10.00' and the 'am'.  The date and time are generated by one function, so I know I will only have to target the .datespan class.

The problem is, I've been reading up on regex for the first time this afternoon and I can't seem to work out how to do this. Will I use the string .replace() method with a regex?

I mean, to say I don't know where to start with this is an understatement.

Any advice or general pointers would be amazing.

JS

```
var dateSpan = document.querySelectorAll(".datespan");

dateSpan.forEach(function(item) {

item.replace(
// remove the space character before the 'am' in the .datespan with a regex
// or find a way to always remove the 3rd from last character in a string
)

});
```

HTML

```
<span class="datespan">January 7, 2018 @ 10:00 am</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the variety of choices you have

```
const original = `January 7, 2018 @ 10:00 am`;
const startStr = original.slice(0, -3);
const endStr = original.slice(-2);
const combined = `${startStr}${endStr}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = "January 7, 2018 @ 10:00 am"
str = str.replace(/\sam$/, "am") // replace the space + "am" at the end of the string with "am" (without a space) 
console.log(str)  // January 7, 2018 @ 10:00am
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the third character from the end of string using `replace(/ (?=.{2}$)/g, '')`.

`(?=.{2}$)` matches the white space followed by (with *look ahead* `?=`) two characters `.{2}` and end of string `$`

```js
var s = 'January 7, 2018 @ 10:00 am'

console.log(
  s.replace(/ (?=.{2}$)/g, '')
)
```